# How can I group an array with dictionaries using a Key value.

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, swift3, nsdictionary

I am working with Json which has response something like this

```
{"Type": "ABCDEF", "user_photo": "c16a8ad9bf08f966.jpg", "time": 1540399975658}
```

So I converted this to below by using a custom function so that I can see the value for `Today, Yesterday, last week, Last month` etc.

```
{"Type": "ABCDEF", "user_photo": "c16a8ad9bf08f966.jpg", "time": "Today"}
```

Now I am trying to display this on a tableview using this structure in different section with each section showing up items of particular time.

All items in today will be in one section. All items in yesterday will be in one section so on.

I have an array of all these responses and I am trying to group them into a dictionary with each key value having the same `time` key. If I am able to solve this I guess using them for sections would be pretty easy

[image: This is what I am trying to achieve.]

I am stuck in this and not quite sure how I could continue on this.

1 solution I tried but failed was to have an array of Times and matching array of responses. Tried grouping Times array but it did not work.

Comment: Update to Swift 4 and use `Dictionary(grouping:by:)`.

Comment: @vadian So I tried using the Swift 4 method but Dictionary(grouping: notifcationsDict, by: { $0["time"]! } ) this method is not working on [[String:Any]] type. It keeps giving me an error Cannot subscript a value of incorrect or ambiguous type

Comment: In the given JSON the type is actually `[[String:String]]` or you have to write `$0["time"] as! String` but I would decode the JSON to structs with `Decodable`.

Comment: I see in one of your comments that you don' t know how many values there might be for "time", is that correct? or is that value in your control? It's a much easier problem if you can control the value of the groups

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an empty dictionary of type [String: [Item]].

```
var dict = [String: [Item]]()
```

Loop through all the items in the original array and make next thing. If there is not a key with the given name, create empty array and append an item, else add item in the existing array.

```
for item in items {
    dict[item.time, default: []].append(item)
}
```

Call `dict["Today"]` and you will get an array of items with the time = "Today".

---

**Swift 4**

```
Dictionary(grouping: items, by: { $0.time })
```

Comment: But the problem is I am not sure How many items will exist like Today, yesterday, 2 days ago, 4 days ago etc etc. There might be 100's of them.

Comment: So I tried using the Swift 4 method but `Dictionary(grouping: notifcationsDict, by: { $0["time"]! } )` this method is not working on [[String:Any]] type. It keeps giving me an error `Cannot subscript a value of incorrect or ambiguous type`

Comment: try it by first unwrapping notificationsDict as [[String:String]] if it matches the format of your second JSON example

Answer (score 1):

You may use array from the original JSON string and then parse it in your own way.

Thus you have separate a grouping question apart from parsing questions.

As shown in the following code and try it in playground.

```
    let array = ["{\"Type\": \"ABCDEF\", \"user_photo\": \"c16a8ad9bf08f966.jpg\", \"time\": \"last week\"}", "{\"Type\": \"ABCDEF\", \"user_photo\": \"c16a8ad9bf08f966.jpg\", \"time\": \"Tomorrow\"}" , "{\"Type\": \"ABCDEF\", \"user_photo\": \"c16a8ad9bf08f966.jpg\", \"time\": \"Today\"}","{\"Type\": \"ABCDEF\", \"user_photo\": \"c16a8ad9bf08f966.jpg\", \"time\": \"Today\"}"]
    let re = try  NSRegularExpression.init(pattern: "(\\\"([^\"])*\\\")[\\s}]+$", options:  [.anchorsMatchLines ,. allowCommentsAndWhitespace])
    let dict =  Dictionary.init(grouping: array) {
            return ($0 as NSString).substring(with: re.matches(in: $0, options: [], range: NSRange.init(location: 0, length: $0.count))[0].range(at: 1))
    }
    print(dict)
```

The result is :

```
 ["\"last week \"": ["{\"Type\": \"ABCDEF\", \"user_photo\": \"c16a8ad9bf08f966.jpg\", \"time\": \"last week \"  }"], "\"Tomorrow\"": ["{\"Type\": \"ABCDEF\", \"user_photo\": \"c16a8ad9bf08f966.jpg\", \"time\": \"Tomorrow\"}"], "\"Today\"": ["{\"Type\": \"ABCDEF\", \"user_photo\": \"c16a8ad9bf08f966.jpg\", \"time\": \"Today\"}", "{\"Type\": \"ABCDEF\", \"user_photo\": \"c16a8ad9bf08f966.jpg\", \"time\": \"Today\"}"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could define a dictionary with all the notifications:

```
var notifcationsDict: [String: [Notification]] = ["Today": [],
                                                  "Yesterday": [],
                                                  "Last week": [],
                                                  "Last month": [],]
```

Define a struct for notifications:

```
struct Notification: Decodable {
    let type, userPhoto, time: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case type = "Type"
        case userPhoto = "user_photo"
        case time
    }
}
```

*(Notice the use of coding keys to conform to the Swift way of naming properties)*

Then you could decode the json and append the notification to the corresponding key in the dictionary:

```
let json = """
{
    "Type": "ABCDEF",
    "user_photo": "c16a8ad9bf08f966.jpg",
    "time": "Today"
}
"""

guard let jsonData = json.data(using: .utf8) else {
    fatalError("Couldn't get the json to data")
}

do {
    let notification = try JSONDecoder().decode(Notification.self, from: jsonData)
    notifcationsDict[notification.time]?.append(notification)
    print(notifcationsDict)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```